# Is there a way to Ignore values by range when displaying in composer?

Tags: graphite

Is there a function in the Graphite URL API which allows us to ignore values which are inside (or outside) a certain range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can check out the [`removeAboveValue`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.removeAboveValue) and [`removeBelowValue`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.removeBelowValue) functions.

For example, to exclude values below 2 and above 10:

```
http://host/render&target=removeAboveValue(removeBelowValue(a.b.c, 2), 10)
```

Ignoring values *inside* a range is a little more difficult, but it can probably be achieved by summing series where data has previously been filtered out (untested):

```
http://host/render&target=sum(removeAboveValue(a.b.c, 2), removeBelowValue(a.b.c, 10))
```